# How to save part of a regular expression during search and replace?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I think the best way to explain what I'm trying to do is using an example. Suppose one would want to replace all underlined words with italic ones in org-mode using a regular expression:

```
_example_ --> /example/
```

Using Perl regex, one could easily accomplish such a task with the grouping variables `$1`, `$2`, etc... using the expression `s/_([^_]+)_/\/$1\//g` for this case.

Are there similar "grouping variables" in Emacs? If not, then what is the most efficient way to perform such a replacement operation?

Comment: You really should *ask Emacs first*. Check the Elisp manual for the Emacs Lisp regexp syntax. You won't get far with regexps without some knowledge of this syntax. The manual is included with Emacs - you just need to hit `C-h i`. Help yourself.

Comment: @Drew Thanks. I checked the manual, but didn't know it was under "eLisp > ... > Regxp Backslash". Found it now, only after I knew what to look for

Comment: **`i`** is your friend in a manual (but yes, you need to guess which manual).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\(...\)`for grouping and `\1` to reference the first saved group (`\2` for the second, all the way up to `\9`). E.g.:

`query-replace-regexp`: `_\([^_]+\)_` into `/\1/`.

See [Regexp Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash) in the Emacs Lisp Manual for more.