# Replace expressions including variable text

Tags: replace

I wish to create a function to put in my `.emacs` (but I am no Elisp expert) in order to perform a certain number of replacements within an Emacs buffer.  In particular, I want to:

- replace any occurrence of `\pnotes{*}` (where `*` is some variable stuff, e.g. `\pnotes{1.73}`, `\pnotes{1.41}`...) with `\notes` followed by a line break
- delete any occurrence of `\ast{*}` (where `*` is some variable stuff, e.g. `\ast{0.03}`, `\ast{.70}`...)
- replace any occurrence of `\nextvoice` with the same string preceded by a line break
- replace any occurrence of `\ib` with the same string preceded by a line break;
- replace any occurrence of `|` with the same character preceded by a line break
- replace any occurrence of `&` with the same character preceded by a line break
- replace any occurrence of `\en%` with `\en` preceded by a line break

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat replacement until not possible?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7585/repeat-replacement-until-not-possible)

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question. Search for tag `[replace]`. And see the Elisp manual, node [Search and Replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html).

Comment: No, it does not answer my question because my main difficulty is to replace expressions including variables, as explained in my post.  Thanks.

Comment: Then [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51707/105). It keeps the part you want to remove instead of the part you want to keep, but the idea and answer are the same. And [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4214/105) can help. And [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/105) says how to inject the value of a variable into Lisp code, if you're really talking about using *a variable* and not *variable text* (your question suggests the latter, but it's unclear).

Comment: Start by defining a keyboard macro, with `^X(`, then type the emacs commands to do what you want, then `^X)` and `ESC X edit-last-kbd-macro` to see the recorded elisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your questions have a solution involving replacements using regular expressions.
Browse for

```
(info "(emacs) Regular Expression Search")
```

. You can use M-x re-builder to build a regular expression.

For example

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\\\pnotes {[^}] *}" "\\\\notes
")
```

will solve your first question,

```
C-M-% \\pnotes{[^}]*} RET \\notes C-q C-j RET
```

in interactive mode.

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\\\ast{[^}]*}" "")
```

will solve your second.

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\(\\\\nextvoice\\)" "
\& ")
```

will solve the third and subsequent ones by replacing \\\\nextvoice with an appropriate expression.

In interactive mode, backslashes don't need to be doubled, for example for the last regexp, type

```
C-M-% \(\\nextvoice \) RET C-q C-j \& RET
```

The newline character is inserted by C-q C-j, you will understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".